# Trigger after update on table A or Table B... Table D

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, multiple-tables

I have 4 tables, lets call them  tA, tB, tC, tD. Is it possible To trigger after insert, update or delete on tA OR tB OR tC OR tD?

What I want is to insert on a log if this tables change.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Triggers are ***highly*** vendor-specific - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s on sql-server 2008, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ,you need to create after triggers on each table individually but with same logic.